# Upgrade to 1.9 failed: Invalid backend model specified

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-community, upgrade

I tried upgrading from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9 and it failed horribly using Magento Connect.

I tried using the Rollback feature and it broke it even more.

I backed up all of my files and database.  I wiped out the original installation directory and copied all of my backups accordingly. The basic look of the site is there, but nothing works.

I made no changes to the DB and using the originally installed DB. Links to products don't work but goes to a "The page you requested was not found", and if trying to add certain products to cart it says

> Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice

When I try to do a rollback again it says "Insufficient permissions".

Anyhow, it's really hosed. I figured simply copying the original files back as they were backed up prior to upgrading would just restore the site. Well I guess I was wrong. Can anyone help?

When trying to login this error occurs:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 785873015503

This is the error Report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:89:"Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice";i:1;s:5991:"#0 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
#1 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(205): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
#2 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(998): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->_setAttributeValue(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#3 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(959): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_loadModelAttributes(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '14', NULL)
#5 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '14', NULL)
#6 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(813): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('14')
#7 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(759): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_canReorder(false)
#8 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Reorder.php(61): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->canReorder()
#9 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/recent.phtml(62): Mage_Sales_Helper_Reorder->canReorder(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#10 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/roninask...')
#11 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Recent.php(70): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Recent->_toHtml()
#15 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('top', true)
#17 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/design/frontend/ASKChemicals/default/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('top')
#18 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/roninask...')
#19 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ASKChe...')
#20 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(522): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('customer_accoun...', true)
#24 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#25 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#26 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/design/frontend/ASKChemicals/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(62): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/roninask...')
#32 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ASKChe...')
#33 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#36 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#37 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(115): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#38 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#39 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#40 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#41 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#42 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#43 /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

---

And this is what's in the system log:

```
2014-07-20T11:20:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Startdate/Specialprice.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/local:/home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/community:/home1/roninask/public_html/mg/app/code/core:/home1/roninask/public_html/mg/lib:.:/opt/php52/lib/php')  in /home1/roninask/public_html/mg/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

---

Comment: Have you restored the database back to the version you backed up along with the files?

Comment: Do you have a snapshot of your site before you upgraded including the Database and the Site code? The important thing will be your database as you can restore your code 1.7 files

Comment: Magento Rollbacks stink, the only effective backup to restore to is a complete recursive public_html tarball and database dump. Essentially you do a database table drop/public_html wipe and reload the database and application. Doing experiments like this on your live e-commerce website always costs you sales, in future, use a dev server and test mightily before committing your source of income to prevent devastation.

Comment: I restored the DB and it's functioning correctly now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 8):

The backend model which Magento tries to use according to your error message `Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice` was defined in CE 1.9.

You did not restore your database after the setup with your backup-version. The new backend model of CE 1.9 `catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice` is defined in a table in the database and Magento is looking for this model in your CE 1.7 files which you copied back.

Please restore your database with the database backup you hopefully created before the update.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up having a similar thought that the upgrade made changes to the DB. After reading your post I restored the DB and it's back to working as it should be. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Great it worked!

Comment: Hey, can we use the  magento 1.9 `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Startdate_Specialprice` .I guss that we can use.What is your thought

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Magento, I'm new here. But I know a bit about systems in general.

1. Did you backup the database as well, and did you restore it ?
2. When you backed up and copied back the original magento site, did you keep the permissions as they were?

From you log message, a `.php` file cannot be included. Is it because the permissions are not correct or because the script cannot find the file. Check also your `include_path`